# Transferring Funds from SS58 Account to H160 Account Using Frontier and Metamask

Tags: frontier, metamask

I've successfully integrated `Frontier` into my runtime and have accessed the funds from an account, Alice's, using its SS58 account. To achieve this, I truncated the public address to retrieve the H160 address.

Currently, I am looking to transfer some of these funds to another Metamask account, for which I have the private key. The target account is in H160 format.

My stumbling block is understanding the process of transferring funds from Alice's SS58 account to the H160 target account. Could anyone shed light on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using the Frontier's `polkadot-v0.9.39`, so there is no `AccountId20` there yet, right?

You can use PolkadotJS UI to send an `evm.call()` extrinsic, like:

[image]

Encoded call data:

```
0x0801d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c855800000000000000000000000000000000000000000430000064a7b3b6e00d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a08601000000000000ca9a3b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Alice's SS58 account is allowed to "impersonate" that H160 account in the EVM context.